# multiple effect-adjusted sounds through audio units on IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audiounit

If I have 5 sounds which all use a varispeed audio unit which different parameters, do I have to use an audio unit per set of parameters. Important to note with diffirent parameters I mean I cannot mix the 5 sounds together BEFORE I put them through a varispeed audio unit.

If I have to use different audio units does this impact my memory usage of performance? And would there be better ways of doing this?
Thanks,
Jan

PS: this is also posted on apple dev forums but they barely EVER answer, I will copy any solid  answer to that post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run these audio units with different parameters (and in real-time), then you will need multiple units, one for each set of parameters.  Speed resamplers, when fed short buffers, don't use much memory.

Comment: is this also applicable to low pass? I would need a vari and a low pass for each sound and will have quite a few sounds